# Traduction de « tag » dans un langage comme HTML

Tags: anglais, informatique

Je recherche la traduction la plus appropriée pour le mot « tag », qui est utilisé pour nommer les composants d'un langage comme HTML ou XML. Par exemple, on pourrait parler de *tag* dans un système de *templates* (modèles??).

Comment: C'est une question très spécifique sur l'informatique. Il y a des forums d'informatique sur SE. Ou alors il faut poser la question autrement, expliquer ce qu'est en français ce mot recherché et proposer une solution qui pourrait être commentée.

Comment: La traduction est différente suivant les cas (markup, classification, …).

Comment: la traduction de « *tag* » est « *balise* » ; la traduction de « *template* » est « *patron* » et « *placeholder* » n'a pas de traduction exacte, c'est soit « *espace* », « *indicateur* » en général avec un qualificatif (la source étant l'ensemble de mes cours en info n'utilisant que des mots en Français).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le mot que je cherchais était "balise". Cet [article sur Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langage_de_balisage) correspond exactement à ce que je voulais dire. Désolé pour l'imprécision de la question.

Comment: Le *placeholder* en HTML est une indication complémentaire avec le label, pour guider l'utilisateur sur la valeur attendu d'un champ de formulaire. J'ai du mal à le traduire par *balise*...

Comment: En fait c'était ma question qui était mauvaise. Je recherchais le terme anglais que je connaissais qui était le plus proche que je cherchais était *placeholder*, mais après vérification, vous avez raison, ce n'est pas un  terme approprié. Je supprime ma réponse ou ma question alors?

Comment: Ni l'un ni l'autre, édite plutôt ta question pour qu'elle corresponde mieux à ton besoin (même si tu as maintenant ta réponse, ça peut toujours servir à quelqu'un d'autre).

Comment: En fait, tu cherchais la traduction de _tag_ et non de _placeholder_.